# DIV width depend on IMG width

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="item">
    <img src="/images/01.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="item">
    <img src="/images/02.jpg" />
</div>
```

I want to give "width" to each DIV(item) depend on width of image in it.
each width of images is different.

Comment: Must you use jQuery for this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use jQuery for that. You can achieve it entirely through CSS. If you float the item and then clear it, you will achieve the expected result:

```
div {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mBGCJ/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wait for the images to be loaded before the width is calulated

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.item img').load(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().width( $this.width());
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5d677/)

*Also the ID of the element must be unique, so I changed the ID to a class value*

Answer (score 0):

Edit you HTML. ID's must be unique.

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="/images/01.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="/images/02.jpg" />
</div>


.item
{
   padding:1px 1px 1px 1px;
   margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Among other answers, my suggestion is to set the following CSS for the elements

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wSLMV/

Notice that I simply refer to the tags (`div` and `img`). You would probably want to refer to `#item` but **be aware that `id` attribute must be unique!** You probably want to replace it with `class`, e.g.

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="/images/01.jpg" />
</div>
```

and then refer to it in CSS:

```css
.item {
    display: inline-block;
}
.item > img {
    display: block;
}
```